# path in FileField django

Tags: python, django, filefield

I prepared my model to create PDF filled by all the fields it includes and I try to to link generated file to the `pdf = models.FileField()`. However the path to the file seems to be ok I can't reach the file through the view.

**models.py:**

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
    # fields
    # ...
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to = 'pdfs/', default = None, blank = True)



    def render_template(self, request):
        #some magic

        BASE_DIR = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent)
        file_name = 'myfile'

        os.system(f"pdflatex -halt-on-error  --output-directory={BASE_DIR}/media/pdfs  {BASE_DIR}/media/tex/rendered/{file_name}")
        os.system(f"rm {BASE_DIR}/media/tex/rendered/{file_name}.tex")
        os.system(f"rm {BASE_DIR}/media/pdfs/{file_name}.aux")
        os.system(f"rm {BASE_DIR}/media/pdfs/{file_name}.log")
        return f"{BASE_DIR}/media/pdfs/{file_name}.pdf"
```

**views.py:**

```
def create_lesson(request):
    lesson = Lesson()
    lesson.pdf = lesson.render_template(request)
    lesson.save()
    message = {
        'tag' : 'success',
        'body' : "Successfully added new lesson!"
     }
     return JsonResponse({'message' : message})
```

But when putting `<a href="{{ lesson.pdf }}">CLICK TO VIEW FILE</a>` the link directs to:
`http://localhost:8000/docs/lessons/media/pdfs/myfile.pdf`

What path should be set to pdf field to direct to `media/pdf/myfile.pdf` in `models.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
<a href="/media/{{ lesson.pdf }}">CLICK TO VIEW FILE</a>
```

After using the above code, you will be redirected to this path `media/pdf/myfile.pdf`